# Why handset manufacturers releases new versions of android several months after Google?

Tags: updates

I have a nexus device. Whenever new version of android is released, the phone gets it almost instantly. I want to know why other manufacturers doesn't update their software in the same timespan. For some manufacturers, this process can take several months.

**Is there a technical challenge that prevents them to do this?** or is just matter of not allocating enough resources to do this?

I know about the differences between different ROMs and manufacturers, UI layers and so on... I'm asking is if so difficult (and why), or if manufacturers just don't want to do it, to release the new ROMs earlier.

To give an example about what I'm saying: when I updated from Windows 7/8 to Windows 10 in several computers (MSI, Acer, Lenovo, and custom build), I just clicked the "update" button and all the computers updated fine, without drivers problems... Why android is not the same case? Every major release introduces several **breaking** changes that makes it difficult for manufacturers?

Comment: @beeshyams Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: See [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/65587/120021) on the question [Is there a technical reason Android update story is so bad?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65557/is-there-a-technical-reason-android-update-story-is-so-bad?rq=1)

Comment: Another important technical reason: They can't just simply pick the image and roll it out. Hardware is different, so they need to intgrate specific drivers etc.pp. For details, also see: [Is there an official Android “Google” ROM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15717/16575) / [Why are there different versions of each firmware for different country?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/82520/16575) / [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575)

Comment: @beeshyams when you follow Enigma's request and write an answer, feel free to "copy" from my comment :)

Comment: @Izzy updated my question. I know that android is very fragmented with several differences between roms and manufacturers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help to go through this graphic:

Notice that the graphic has a blue 'Google Play Edition' path which was when non-Nexus manufacturer had devices with only stock Android. This blue line would be the closest approximation to a Nexus device and notice how it doesn't have as many blocking points as the orange 'Carrier Device'.

*Comparing to PC*

You have to realize that the PC Hardware layer is relatively standardized on a x64 architecture either from Intel or AMD.

Android has multiple CPU architectures to support (ARMv7,ARMv8,x86,x64,MIPS) manufactured by different vendors (Samsung, Qualcomm, NVidia, Rockchip, Intel, MIPS) and its in Step 5 that the various vendors have to see what will get support. Way more customization goes on here than a normal PC.

[image: HTC Software Update Process]

Originally from:
http://www.htc.com/us/go/htc-software-updates-process/

Comment: Yes. That is how such questions should be addressed. Not by pure speculation or mix up of opinions as technical facts but by hard facts which comes straight from sources officially hosted by vendors/OEMs or by Google.

Comment: Didn't realize that the image is duping the answer to: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65557/is-there-a-technical-reason-android-update-story-is-so-bad?rq=1 Go there for other canonical answer from Sony http://android.stackexchange.com/a/65746/3573

Answer (score 1):

IMO , [izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139901/why-handset-manufacturers-releases-new-versions-of-android-several-months-after?noredirect=1#comment179334_139901), [benjaminS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139901/why-handset-manufacturers-releases-new-versions-of-android-several-months-after?noredirect=1#comment179333_139901) have pointed you to several reasons as to why it is complicated. I am consolidating these inputs to answer **technical reasons**

Let's get business reasons out of way first. [Nexus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus) devices

> are considered Google's flagship Android products (...) Nexus devices are often among the first Android devices to receive updates to the operating system.(*linkage should be obvious*)

## Fragmentation is the key

[Update process graphic](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/65587/131553) pointed out by benjaminS, beautifully illustrates steps involved. Steps 4 and 5 are hardware related , which is **heavily fragmented** . This is a major challenge.

Let's start  by taking the example of Samsung, which launched Note 2 devices, in two variants,which are identical in all respects, except the chip set (Exynos , homegrown Samsung processor and Snapdragon). This led to different ROMs being developed , tested and ported and released at different dates (don't remember the specifics, was about 4 months as I recall-talking of international versions). This is with only critical hardware difference. Next, consider various other hardware elements-screen, camera, earphones to name a few others and fragmentation mushrooms. Add to that  low cost competition coming up with [rebranded](http://www.droidiser.com/2012/10/exclusive-truth-behind-indian.html?m=1) devices and the panorama of fragmentation grows huge. Hence,

- OEMs have to [customise](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/15719/131553) ROMs from source code. Adding bloatware and customised UI takes more time
- ROMs have to be [different](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35928/131553) for different hardware, though they may be similar in other ways
- ROMs have to be [country /region specific](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/82599/131553) **even** if the hardware is same
- Carriers add their own value and time penalty

it should be pretty obvious now why rolling out is delayed and comparing this scenario with PCs didn't hold given the standardised architecture

**Edit:**  By the time I got down to preparing this answer, see that another answer had been posted, having an overlap

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, other manufacturers have to update their skin and extra features they introduce with the product. Not everything would be compatible so they test it till everything is fixed! Moreover, there is this whole career thing, which is super complicated. Therefore, other's have to wait. While on the nexus devices, they are on Pure Stock Android with no customization. Thus, Google controls the updates and they get updates quite quickly.

EDIT:
The complications of the career is explained beautifully in a howtogeek article, you may want to check it out:
http://www.howtogeek.com/163958/why-do-carriers-delay-updates-for-android-but-not-iphone/

Comment: Why is super complicated? That's my question :)

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta Did the new edit I did help you?

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta It's complicated because manufacturers often make it complicated with lots of third-party alterations, customizations, and often a bunch of bloat. If they also just ported and released stock android, their job would be much easier and would primarily focus on hardware compatibility.